# Possible to set the focus to same control in onblur event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to have the focus on same button even after losing the focus.

I kept the code for your reference.

OnSuccess is the blur event for the button btnOK.

```
    function OnSuccess() {
       document.getElementById('btnOk').focus();
       return true;
    }
```

During tab press on the btnOK, It loses the focus.How to stay back the focus in the same control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function OnSuccess() {
  setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById('btnOk').focus();
    }, 0);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Akhil: This is what I want.Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Karthik. I'm a great fan of Sachin too... :)